# Magento 2.3.0 | How to convert custom popup into PDF and Download

Tags: magento2.3, pdf, convert

I am having an Custom popup code which appears on the product page, I need to download this as PDF, I tried with dumpdf but couldn't succeeded. My code is following:

```
<?php
$prodArr = $this->getProdArr();;
$prodName =  $prodArr[0];
$prodSku =  $prodArr[1];
?>
<div class="modal fade" id="authentic-certificate" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" >

        <div class="modal-body">
            <div id ="html-pdf">
               <h2 class ="cc_name" ><center><img style="width:51%" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA); ?>wysiwyg/icotheme/zeus/logo/cc-logo-010.png"></center></h2>
               <h3 class="certificate_of_authenticity" ><span>CERTIFICATE OF AUTHENTICITY</span></h3>
               <P class="cerification">We certify that, to the best of knowledge the product,</P>
               <p><span class="prod_name"><?php echo $prodName; ?></span></p>
               <P class ="sku"> <span >SKU:<?php echo $prodSku; ?></span></P>
               <P class ="certification_text" >you have purchased is 100% authentic and guaranteed for its workmanship. The products sold on our platform is in accordance with the recognised industrial quality standards.</P>
               <img class="certificate-image" src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN);?>frontend/zeus/default/images/authentic-certificate-001.png">
               <img class="authentic_partner_image"  src="<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN);?>frontend/zeus/default/images/authentic-partner.png">
           </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Basically you need to use library for this task:** you can use **TCPDF** or **FPDF**.

I prefer TCPDF - Link: [Click Here](https://tcpdf.org/)

**Step1.** First you need to import this library in your code.

**Step2.** Then You need to convert this html into Pdf.